# Lightning: running an apex method on a button that returns string, returns [object Object]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Been crash course learning Lightning. Just trying to get a simple apex button to work and having some issues:

my component

```
<aura:component controller="testjzapex">
      <!--<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />-->
    <ui:button label="banana" press="{!c.echo}"/>

      <aura:attribute name="Name" type="String" default="test1" />
    <aura:attribute name="Name2" type="String" default="banana1" />



    <div class="slds">
    <form class="slds-form--inline">
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="slds-input" value = "{!v.Name}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="email">Email2</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
      <input type="text" id="email" class="slds-input" value = "{!v.Name2}"  />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--brand">Send</button>
  </div>

</form>
        </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    echo : function(cmp) {

       var banana = cmp.get("c.getBanana")
       cmp.set("v.Name2",banana);

    },
})
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class testjzapex {
        @AuraEnabled
        public static String getBanana()
        {
            return 'banana';
        }

}
```

So when I press the button the field is populated with [object Object] instead of 'banana'. I feel like i'm missing something obvious, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way we get value from the server and use on client:

```
var action = cmp.get("c.getBanana");
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    cmp.set("v.Name2", response.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

So replace the above code for:

```
var banana = cmp.get("c.getBanana")
cmp.set("v.Name2",banana);
```

(Invoking a controller method requires the remote call to be queued and the response comes back some time later and is handled by the callback you set.)

Comment: this worked. Thanks! You are mixing cmp and component though in your answer which gave me an error, but was easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a request to the server, however, you do not get the response. Salesforce's documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) explains how to properly structure the request to the server, based on the example, you can see in the alert, that "banana" is returned after having successfully done the request.

```
({
    echo : function(cmp) {

       var action = cmp.get("c.getBanana");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            // This callback doesn’t reference cmp. If it did,
            // you should run an isValid() check
            //if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // Alert the user with the value returned 
                // from the server
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
                cmp.set("v.Name2", response.getReturnValue());
                // You would typically fire a event here to trigger 
                // client-side notification that the server-side 
                // action is complete
            }
            //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "ERROR") {
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```